# How to work with join data in codeigniter?

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter

I am having a play around with codeigniter and trying to get my head around the active record system and such like.
I have set up a couple of tables and am attempting to run a join on them, as such:

```
function GetOrganisationsAndBuildingDetails()
{
    $this->db->select('organisations.organisation_name,
                       organisations.organisation_id,
                       buildings.building_name,
                       buildings.address1');
    $this->db->from('organisations')->join('buildings', 'buildings.organisation_id = organisations.organisation_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

In my database i have one organisation with two related buildings. The above query returns two objects (one for each building) - however, the organisation is duplicated.

- stdClass Object ( 
  [organisation_name] => This is an example org 
  [organisation_id] => 1 
  [building_name] => test building 
  [address1] => 123456 )
- stdClass Object ( 
  [organisation_name] => This is an example org 
  [organisation_id] => 1 
  [building_name] => teeeest building 
  [address1] => 123456 )

I suppose I was expecting something along the lines of one return object with a series of nested objects for related buildings. Is this possible?
If not, is their a recommend way of arranging the return data so I can easily loop through it in the view? (foreach org, foreach building etc etc).

Apologies if I'm being a little dense here. Im coming from .net and (linq to SQL in particular) where this stuff is a little different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will inevitably return duplicate data as you say, you have to organize them after you get the result like this

```
$buildings = array();

foreach ( $result_object as $organization ) {
    $building_data = array(
        'building_name' => $organization->building_name,
        'address'       => $organization->address,
    );
    $buildings[$organization->organization_name][] = $building_data;
}
```

this way organizations will be "compacted" in the first key of the multidimensional array, and one level deeper you will have info about the buildings.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you here but that code would seem to create an array with the org name as key (correct) and one buildings set of details, as these are getting overwritten with every iteration...

Comment: ah yep! that works. Thanks for your help.
Was hoping there was an automatic way for a model to return nested arrays for associated data...nevermind!